# What to do when one stream depends on the value from another?

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs, frp

I'm new to Rx.js and looking for some basic help with FRP concepts. I have one stream using `generateWithRelativeTime` that keeps a game loop running, and a stream that keeps track of the screen resolution. My problem with my current code is that my game loop only runs when my screen resolution changes.

The stream generated by my model function requires the latest value from res$.

```
function model(res$) {
  return res$.map(res => {
    const rows = ceil(res[1] / CELL.HEIGHT)+1
    const cols = ceil(res[0] / CELL.WIDTH)+1

    return Observable.generateWithRelativeTime(
      initWorld(rows, cols, 1.618),
      noOp,
      world => step(world),
      noOp,
      _ => 100,
      Rx.Scheduler.requestAnimationFrame
    ).timeInterval()
  });
}

function intent() {
  return Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
                   .map(e => [e.currentTarget.innerWidth, e.currentTarget.innerHeight])
                   .debounce(100, Rx.Scheduler.requestAnimationFrame)
                   .startWith([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
}

model(intent())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the joy of FRP. As it is, it is difficult to understand your question. How `What to do when one stream depends on the value from another?` is connected to `My problem with my current code is that my game loop only runs when my screen resolution changes.`? You give the actual behavior, what is your expected behavior?

For my limited understanding of the question, I think that you need to replace this line `return res$.map(res => {` by `return res$.flatMapLatest(res => {`, i.e. use the operator `flatMapLatest` instead of the `map` operator.

To understand the `flatMap` operator, I recommend you to review the following resources : [The introduction to reactive programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754), the [illustrated marbles](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) and the [official documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md).

PS : I see that you seem to follow a MODEL-VIEW-INTENT architecture. Out of curiosity, are you experimenting with `cyclejs`?

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed it. The expected behavior was that the game loop should run, and each time it runs, use the latest resolution from the res$ stream. Now it works :) Thanks!

Comment: Also, yeah I'm playing around with Cycle.js :)

Comment: Nice, could you then accept or upvote the answer to signal that it is correct or useful for other readers who might stumble on this question from a google search?